# TVMaze api error

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am creating a site for listing TV shows and I am using TVMaze api for it. I am beginner in working with JSON so maybe my problem is that, but here is the weird thing happening.

My table is generated with this code:

```
var keyword = "";
var $url = "";

$('#submit').on('click', function (e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    keyword = $('#search').val();
    window.sessionStorage['keyword'] = keyword;
});
if (!window.sessionStorage['keyword']) {
    $url = " http://api.tvmaze.com/shows?page=1";
} else {
    keyword = window.sessionStorage['keyword'].toString();
    keyword = keyword.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "");
    $url = "http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=" + keyword;
    //alert($url);
}

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var $obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        for (var i = 0; i <= $obj.length - 1; i++) {
            var $item = '<div> \
                          <div>\
                              <h2>' + $obj[i].name + '</h2> \
                              <div> ' + $obj[i].rating.average + ' </div>\
                              <p>' + $obj[i].summary + '</p>\
                              <a href="#" id="' + $obj[i].id + '">Track</a>\
                          </div>\
                        </div>';
            $('.show-items-container').append($item);
        }
    }
};
//alert($url);
xmlhttp.open("GET", $url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

So first it checks if there is keyword entered in a search bar and if there isn't it sends a request to the /page=1, and if there is a keyword entered, it should print the show. But, in my case, it reads to url like it is supposed to, but nothing shows up. And if I search that link in the browser it lists the correct show.

For example if I put 'kirby' in the search bar, it reads this url -> http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=kirby , but nothing shows in the table and there are no errors in the console. If you enter that same url in the browser, it works.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: There is a syntax error. You have ` + '` missing, it should be `$obj[i].name + '</h2>\`. Isn't that the issue?

Comment: Sorry about that. I probably deleted it when I was deleting the classes. The syntax is fine, it works except when I enter a keyword. I am using .net MVC4 if that changes things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `onclick` you are not making the xhr request. You call `xmlhttp.open` and `xmlhttp.send` outside of the `click` event so nothing happens on click. Also I noticed you were accessing the wrong property it should be  `$obj[i].show.___` vs `$obj[i].___`

```js
var keyword = "";
var $url = "";
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

function makeRequest() {
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      // clear the current search results
      $('.show-items-container').empty();
      var $obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      for (var i = 0; i <= $obj.length - 1; i++) {
        // make sure you access the correct property
        var $item = `<div>
                        <div>
                          <h2> ${$obj[i].show.name} </h2>
                          <div> ${$obj[i].show.rating.average} </div>
                          <p> ${$obj[i].show.summary} </p>
                          <a href="#" id="${$obj[i].show.id}">Track</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>`;
        $('.show-items-container').append($item);
      }
    }
  }

  // make the xhr request on click
  xmlhttp.open("GET", $url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();

}

$('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
  keyword = $('#search').val();
  $url = "https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=" + keyword;

  // call on click
  makeRequest();
});

// call on page load
makeRequest();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id='search' />

<button type="button" id='submit'>Submit </button>

<div class="show-items-container">
</div>
```

Comment: Well yes, I call it outside of the click event, because it is supposed to make a request on page load and show every show it contains. I also want to call it again after a click is made, to search with a keyword.
Like I said I am beginner in this so maybe I don't know the right way to do it.

Comment: @Spirit_Scarlet so make the request a function, call it on page load and also call it on click. I updated the code